# Kivy Python graphics too slow

Tags: python, optimization, graphics, kivy

I ran into a problem while creating a virtual screen in kivy. I want the application to create an additional screen that can be scaled. I tested kivy.graphics.rectangle, but drawing 10,000 of these rectangles takes almost half a second (the size of the additional screen is approximately 75% of the area and its average resolution is 100 by 100 pixels). is it possible to somehow significantly speed up the drawing?

```
class BCanvas(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BCanvas, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.update_canvas()

    def update_canvas(self, *args):
        self.canvas.clear()
        self.size = Window.size
        self.canvas_size = [100, 100]
        self.padding_x = Window.size[0] * 0.25
        self.padding_y = Window.size[1] * 0.25
        self.pix_size_x = Window.size[0] * 0.75 / self.canvas_size[0]
        self.pix_size_y = Window.size[1] * 0.75 / self.canvas_size[1]
        for i in range(100):
            for o in range(100):
                with self.canvas:
                    Color(i / 100, o / 100, 0)
                    Rectangle(pos = (self.padding_x + i * self.pix_size_x, self.padding_y + o * self.pix_size_y), size = (self.pix_size_x, self.pix_size_y))

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.update_canvas()
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHKzn.png)

Comment: You can do things more efficiently, but when it comes to advanced graphics the best way often depends on exactly what you want to achieve. Can you explain more about what the goal is?

Comment: @inclement I am making a program to simulate the evolution of cells, and this screen is used to display them, I have an array with color values for each cell and they need to be displayed every 1-5 "Cycles".

Comment: So you have an array with 10000 elements, all of which will be updated independently very frequently?

Comment: Yes, every element of the array changes every frame.  I have done this before with pygame, however, it is inconvenient to create an interface with pygame.  Surprisingly, pygame, even using the CPU, was able to show up to 300 fps when rendering 10000+ elements.

Comment: I would try making a Texture to and blitting to it every frame. This can be fairly efficient, but I'm not sure if it will be fast enough for you. This can be further optimised but I'm not sure how straightforward that is. Other kivy developers may know more about this.

Comment: Another optimization would be to represent each element with a single pixel and use one kivy `Rectangle` to stretch the `Texture`  to fit the `BCanvas`. This might show some blurring of the cells, but should be even faster.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I did it like this: I created a texture and filled it using the blit_buffer() function, and it works much faster now. If someone later has a similar problem, here is a detailed instruction on how to do it https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.texture.html